# How to stop people from permanently delete stuff from Git repo?

Tags: git

My understanding is; if a developer does a `git reset --hard <commit>` and `git push --force`, that commit will be permanently deleted from the Git repo.

1. Is there a way to recover the commit from the above action?
2. How can we or shall we stop this type of actions?

Answer (score 1):

1. The commit will be deleted during `git gc` if there are no other references left to that commit. That commit may be referenced by a tag or other branch and in this case it won't be deleted.
   If you recently checked out this commit locally you may find it in `git reflog`.
2. See link in comment by @AlexanderGuz.